# how to put something in only 1 item from a foreach loop (using laravel)

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach

I am trying to give my first item a class active in this loop. But the second and third item may not have class 'active'.

```
            @foreach ($news as $newsitem)
                <div class="item">
                    <div style="background:url({{$newsitem->media->file_url}}) center center; 
                              background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                          <h2>{{$newsitem->title}}</h2>
                          <p>{{ Str::limit($newsitem->content, 30)}} </p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `$key => $val` and check if `$key` iterator is `0`:

```
@foreach ($news as $key => $newsitem)
  <div class="item {{ $key === 0? 'active' : '' }}">
    <div style="background:url({{$newsitem->media->file_url}}) center center; 
                background-size:cover;" class="slider-size">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>{{$newsitem->title}}</h2>
        <p>{{ Str::limit($newsitem->content, 30)}} </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
@endforeach
```